# NSTimer stops the first time I tell it to, then refuses to stop

Tags: iphone, ios, nstimer

I have declared an `NSTimer` in my `UIViewController` header as such:

```
NSTimer *mainTimer;
```

And I start it up in the `viewWillAppear` method in the implementation, so:

```
mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateAll) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

I have a button that flips the view over (standard utility app template) called `showInfo` and it has the command:

```
[mainTimer invalidate];
```

When my app launches, the timer starts and does it's thing.  The first time I tap that button and the view flips, the timer stops.  When I'm done with the `flipSideViewController` and the main view reappears, the timer starts again.  So far, good.  The problem is that subsequent button presses (and thus calls to `[mainTimer invalidate]` don't make the timer stop.  It just keeps going.  I can flip back and forth all I want and it continues to update.  For grins, I put two `invalidate` calls in a row, but that crashes.

UPDATE:

Found the problem.  Upon returning from the `flipSideViewController`, I was calling `viewWillAppear` myself, which would create the timer.  The run loop also calls `viewWillAppear` automatically, so a second timer was created.  This only happened after I had visited the flip side once so the timer (single instance) would stop normally when I flipped the first time.  Odd that I can create two timers with the same name though...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once a timer is invalidated, it will never fire again.

Thus, if the "timer keeps going", then it is a different timer.   Make sure that you are speaking to the instances you think you are.  I've seen quite a few bugs where developer alloc/init an instance and then load a NIB and cause a different instance of a particular class to come into play.  I could see something similar happening here.

Note that it is impossible to invalidate a timer in the dealloc of the object that is the target of the timer.  The timer will retain the target and, thus, the target cannot be [correctly] deallocated within the timer first being invalidated.

Comment: I put a log comment right before where I start the timer and where I invalidate it.  When I return from the flipside, I see the timer get started twice.

Comment: You were right - I had more than one timer.  I called `viewWillAppear` when dismissing the modal view and of course the run loop calls it too, thus two timers.  Odd that it's ok to instantiate two timers with the same name and no warning or crash...

Comment: Excellent.  Happy to help.   Note that liberal use of `NSLog(@"<%@ %p>", [self class], self);` can be quite helpful.

Comment: I've become a huge fan of NSLog (actually I found some alternates that go in my .pch file that make things more or less verbose depending whether I'm in debug or release configs).  But I'd still like to know how I can instantiate two or more timers with the same name and not have a problem.  And if this is an autoreleased object, should I be retaining it when I create it?  And does it matter if it's a property or not?  I know, lots of questions...

Answer (score 2):

I just did exactly the same, and it seems to work for me. What I did in the xcode template:

Go to MainViewController.h and type:

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <FlipsideViewControllerDelegate> {
    NSTimer* timer;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSTimer* timer;

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender;

@end
```

Go to MainViewController.m and add:

```
@synthesize timer;

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"Timer!");
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateAll) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void) updateAll {
    NSLog(@"run");
}

- (IBAction)showInfo:(id)sender {    
    [timer invalidate];
    FlipsideViewController *controller = [[FlipsideViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipsideView" bundle:nil];
    controller.delegate = self;

    controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
    [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

    [controller release];
}
```

Just that, and it runs well for me. Does this help somehow? Maybe your problem is somewhere else - what do you do in `updateAll`?

Comment: I just did exactly the same, with the same result. Strange.

Comment: Found the problem.  I was calling `[self viewWillAppear]` when I dismissed the modal view controller.  So after the first time through, I'd be making two timers.  `viewWillAppear` got called once by me and once by the run loop.

Comment: That explains it. Maybe you should post that comment as an answer and accept it and/or update your question so that people find the right answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

From the docs for `[NSTimer invalidate]`:

> Stops the receiver from ever firing
>   again and requests its removal from
>   its run loop.

So I would call invalidate and then release your timer. It doesn't look like you're retaining on the timer in the first place. So, retain the timer when you make it, invalidate it when you want to, then release after the invalidate.

Next viewWillAppear, make sure you're making and retaining on a new timer.

Comment: [I'm also learning here..] But is it ok to release the timer, when you never initialize it? Shouldn't the mainTimer take care of its own memory, meaning that you can use scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval as many times as you want?

Comment: Releasing the timer after I invalidated it causes a crash.  I believe invalidating it also releases it (read the documentation yesterday...)

Comment: @Irene- by calling scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval, you're receiving an autoreleased timer- this means that it will be released at the end of the current run loop. You have to retain on that timer to keep it around.

Comment: While debugging this, I went from just declaring the timer, to making it a property with nonatomic and retain.  Does this keep it from being autoreleased?  Because I'm not retaining it anywhere else, and yet it just keeps running.

Comment: Yes, if the property has the attribute of retain and you set it using the property setter (dot notation or setTimer:), it will retain automatically (if you've @synthesized the timer).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible viewWillAppear is called several times.

You should make sure the timer is invalidated before creating it

```
[mainTimer invalidate];
mainTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(updateAll) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

Of course, if you are also invalidating the timer on some other place, you should assign it to null.

```
[mainTimer invalidate];
mainTimer = NULL;
```